# favicon not show if page have querystring

Tags: query-string, show, favicon

Favicon is displayed fine if the URL have no querystring, while it does't show if the URL contain querystring!!

Here are the page without querystring:
www.NoonOffer.com

Here are the page with querystring
http://www.noonoffer.com/Offers.aspx/7/Pay-LE-50-and-get-50-discount-on-PMP-course

Any suggestions?

Comment: That is not a query string.  That's some kind of URL routing.

Comment: Yes, it is. and it seems it have a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url doesn't appear to be correct. Something in your code is not putting the proper URL in the HREF.

It is:
http://www.noonoffer.com/Offers.aspx/7/favicon.png

Should be:
http://www.noonoffer.com/favicon.png

EDIT: Not sure with .NET, but using Core Tag Library with Java Spring MVC a "/" at the front of the URL will make a difference when using relative paths.

This would append it to the end of the URI I believe:

```
<c:url value="/favicon.png">
```

And I believe this would append it to the context root like you want.

```
<c:url value="favicon.png">
```

This may not be the exact issue, but I hope it will help.

Comment: Probably you are right since I am rewrite the URL. can you tell me how did you know that the image served url is as you mentioned?

Comment: I viewed the page source for the links you provided, found the favicon link and looked at the URL's for each.

Comment: okay but both pages shows href="favicon.png" in the source, how did you know that the URL in the href is http://www.noonoffer.com/Offers.aspx/7/favicon.png !!?

Comment: When viewing in chrome page source, it shows just the file name as a link, right click and copy link location should copy the URL to your clipboard, you can them paste it somewhere to see it.

Comment: thanks in helping me define the problem, I will check my URL rewrite code to find the solution.